# MongoDB - Get Monday of store date in collection for comparision

Tags: database, mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

How Can I get Monday or Specific Day from stored date in database collection using mongodb aggregate framework?

Are there any oprerators or functions?

This will help me to further comparions while aggregate pipelines.

Yes, There is workground We can store 2 date actual date and Monday date but I need a best solusion instead of storing 2 dates in collection.

Like We get week number using $week(dateField) or $isoWeek(dateField)

Example
I stored date 20-Nov-2019 which is Wednesday. I need a field with the date of Monday of the week - 18-Nov-2019.

Comment: If I understand correctly from the post, you have dates (as fields) in the documents, and you need to extract Monday of that particular week of that date? Would increase visibility on the problem if you can update documents and expected o/p as well in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb`s`$dayOfWeek`on`ISODate()` field. Have look at this [Mongo Play Around](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VH9v7f5nafW)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    day: {
      $dayOfWeek: "$publishedDate.date"
    },
    "publishedDate.date": 1
  }
},
{
  $match: {
   "day": 2
  }
}
])
```

This query returns only Monday date of stored date field. Here note that date is returned as a number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday). In your case it's 18-Nov-2019 returns.